# Control over google map markers placed by users

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

In a nutshell; I would like to have **greater administration control** over google map markers placed by users on my website. (Aim is to stop time wasters and spammers.)

I would like the user, after initially logging in to my website, to be able to place markers on the google maps provided in the form of a **request**, which will then be accepted or declined by the admin (myself).

While the marker request is waiting authentication, it will be invisible to other users and not published to the website.

If the request is accepted, the marker will be published to the website for all other users to see.

If the request is declined then it won't be published to the website and consequently deleted.

It may be a lot to ask but is there anyway to input this concept into my website, through html code and google maps api (UI event function)?

(I have been using this link for my progress so far - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting Use Case.

However, the solution to this would be fairly simple. The key method in this whole implementation would be ***setVisible()***. Here are the steps you can try implementing this:

- First step would be giving the users an opportunity to create a marker on the Map. You can write the code in a **createMarker()** method. Make sure you set the visibility of that marker as false, ***setVisbility(false)***. This would restrict the user to see the marker they have created.
- Second step would be to save that marker. This could be done by using the **getPosition()** method that would fetch the lat and lang values. Offcourse you would need to create a table to store.
- Finally, you would need to figure out based on the location and content  available in the DB to display that marker. This can be done with the help of a simple UI where you approve or reject the marker. With the help of some listeners you can change the visibility to ***true***.

For basic code, please refer to this [tutorial](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/10/google-map-v3-editing-saving-marker-in-database).